# After making new object,i want to make a function that will ask to input the needed arguments into the object

Tags: java

I'm learning java and just started using objects.
I made a class called Polynom ,and declared a few function that i can do on that given polinom.

Now i want to build a function (or a constructor) that as soon as i declare new Polynom ( `Polynom Polynom = new Polynom();` ) , I want to console to ask for input for the polinom.

This is the code snipped i use to "input" the polinom.

```
System.out.println("Please enter the higest rank of your polynom");
    int rank = Scanner.nextInt();
    Polynom.setRank( rank );
    for(int i = 0 ; i < rank+1  ; i++ ){
        System.out.println("Please enter the coefficient of x^" + i);
        double coefficient = Scanner.nextDouble();
        Polynom.setCoef(coefficient, i);
    }
```

And i am having trouble figuring out how to aplly this as soon as i declare a new polinom.

I think maybe in the contractor call a function that will do it,but i cant figure it out.

I have just started using objects and classes ,so please no complicated staff.

This is the code of my work till now

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Polynom {
    static Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double[] coefficients;

public  void setRank(int rank){
    coefficients = new double[rank+1];
}

public double compute(double vlaue){
    double result = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < coefficients.length ; i++){
        result = result + (coefficients[i] * Math.pow(vlaue, i));
    }
    return result;
}

public void setCoef(double coefficient,int power){
    coefficients[power] = coefficient;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Polynom Polynom = new Polynom();

    System.out.println("Welcome to the polynom vlaue calculaor");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Please enter the higest rank of your polynom");
    int rank = Scanner.nextInt();
    Polynom.setRank( rank );
    for(int i = 0 ; i < rank+1  ; i++ ){
        System.out.println("Please enter the coefficient of x^" + i);
        double coefficient = Scanner.nextDouble();
        Polynom.setCoef(coefficient, i);
    }
    System.out.println("Please enter the number to calculate from");
    double from  = Scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter the number to calculate to");
    double to  = Scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of each jump");
    double jump  = Scanner.nextDouble();

    for(double i = from ; i < to ; i = i+jump){
        System.out.println("for x = "+i+" The value is = "+Polynom.compute(i));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you post the code of the class itself ? The answer depends on how you built the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Polynomial
{       
    double[] cofficients;
    public Polynomial(Scanner sc)
    {           
        readpoly(sc);
    }
    public void readpoly(Scanner sc)
    {
       if(sc==null)
          return;
       System.out.println("Please enter the higest rank of your polynom");
       int rank = sc.nextInt();
       cofficients=new double[rank+1];
       for(int i = 0 ; i < rank+1  ; i++ ) 
       {
           System.out.println("Please enter the coefficient of x^" + i);
           cofficients[i]=sc.nextDouble();
       }
    }
}
```

then you can simply create the object like this :

```
 Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
 Polynomial p=new Polynomial(scanner);
```

and the input is taken from console.

that way you can use the same scanner multiple times(to read multiple polynomials) without having to store a whole unrelated object in the Polynomial class.

and I advise you not to name variables by class names(or any other name used before).

Comment: Instead of doing cofficients=new double[rank+1]; i made a function that did that can i impalement it ?

Comment: @Pure_eyes the function I made is better because seperating the build of the array from filling it will leave it filled with zeros unintentionally sometimes

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to pass the information in the constructor? Something like this:

```
class Polynom {

  private int rank;
  private double[] coeffs;

  public Polynom(double[] coeffs) {
     this.rank = coeffs.length - 1;
     this.coeffs = coeffs;
  }
}

Polynom mypoly = new Polynom(new double[]{1.0, 2.0, 3.0});
```

However, if you do it this way, you'll need to store the inputs temporarily while the user is entering them, then create the Polynom in a single operation once you have all the coefficients.